# How to combine two data frames by equal elements

Tags: r

I have two data frames containing the names of genetic elements. I want another data frame with the elements in common in both data frames. 
Example:

```
data.a      data.b
   Column     Column
1  a          c
2  b          e
3  c          l
4  d          a
```

I want this result:

```
data.c
   Column
1   a
2   c
```

This is just an example. The data frame `data.b` has more elements than `data.a`.

Answer (score 1):

The `%in%` operator lets you find which elements are in both.

```
data.c = data.frame(Column = data.a$Column[data.a$Column %in% data.b$Column])
data.c
  Column
1      a
2      c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- data.frame(a = c("a","b","c","d"))
a
b <- data.frame(b = c("c","d","e","f"))
b
c <- data.frame(c = a[a$a %in% b$b,])
c
```

Comment: Adding a brief explanation of *how* the above solves the problem will make it more useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

The merge function allows you control the type of join you want.

`df1 <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c("c", "e", "l", "a"))
merge(x=df1, y=df2, by.x="a", by.y="a", all = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
data.a <- data_frame(a = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
data.b <- data_frame(a = c("c", "e", "l", "a"))
data.c <- data.a %>% inner_join(data.b)
```